# While a partir dos resultados de um select - PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql

Olá, preciso criar um while dentro de uma procedure. Preciso fazer um select antes e a partir dos registros que esse select retornar fazer uma inserção...

Exemplo:
Consulta buscando os dados de um doador que não está na tabela de fidelizados, os resultados que essa consulta retornar precisam ser inseridos em outra tabela um a um...

Podem me ajudar?

O que foi feito até agora.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `gerenciar_fidelizados` ()
BEGIN
    -- Declarando as variáveis 
    DECLARE _idDetentora INT; -- ID da operadora detentora do cadastro Fidelizado (Tabela operadora_fidelizados)
    DECLARE _idDoador INT; -- ID do doador (Tabela operadora_fidelizados)
    DECLARE _idDoadorInsert INT; -- ID do doador fidelizado que ainda não está na tabela dos fidelizados
    DECLARE _idDetentoraInsert INT; -- ID da operadora detentora do doador que ainda não está na tabela de fidelizados

    -- Consulta para buscar os Fidelizados que ainda não estão na tabela que vincula a operadora detentora ao seu doador
    SELECT 
        contribuinte_id_operadora
        , contribuinte_id
    FROM
        contribuintes INNER JOIN entidades ON contribuinte_id_entidade = entidade_id    
    WHERE
        contribuinte_categoria LIKE '%Fidelizado%'
        AND Desativado = 0
        AND entidade_ativa = 1
        AND contribuinte_id NOT IN(SELECT operfid_id_doador FROM operadora_fidelizado)
        AND contribuinte_id_operadora <> 0
        AND contribuinte_id_operadora IS NOT NULL
    INTO
        _idDoadorInsert,
        _idDetentoraInsert;
END
```

Comment: Mostre o que você já fez e onde está tendo dificuldades, também faça o tour do sistehttps://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Acho que você está procurando por algo chamado de `cursor`, para percorrer o seu select e depois inseri-las em determinada tabela.